# Comprehensive source of skin effect depths vs frequncy in different metals or method to calculate?

Tags: data

Is there a comprehensive source of skin effect depths vs frequency for different metals?  I'm looking for Iridium and Osmium specifically, but it would be good to have them all if possible.  Ideally in the format of measured data points so I could just use the least-square algorithm to get the equation for each of them so I can fine tune an experiment based on other parameters (e.g. density, cost, electronegativity, etc.)  Any comprehensive datasets or formulas to derive the equations relevant to different metals (if that's possible without measurement) would be appreciated, but especially so for Iridium and Osmium.

Is the formula listed [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect#Formula) close enough to measured results to be reliable in itself?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no source that gives you the skin effect depths as a function of frequency for different materials because there is a [simple formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) that relates it to the parameters specific resistivity $\rho$, absolute permittivity $\epsilon$ and absolute permeability $\mu$ of the conductor. These parameters can be easily found in standard compilations of physical data, and thus also the frequency dependent skin depth, .

Comment: Any idea where I can find a table of those values for each element?

Comment: It is easy to find data for pure elements. But when cost is a consideration, one might choose a commercial grade of lower purity and higher resistivity. Such information should be in the specs of the suppliers.

Comment: @CoryG - You might find it, e.g., in Springer Handbook of Condensed Matter and Materials Data https://books.google.com/books?id=TnHJX79b3RwC&pg=PA1102&lpg=PA1102&dq=springer+data+electrical+properties+materials&source=bl&ots=dEH8A9IQ68&sig=64rfk0g7S_HjjMByijv1Me6M7S4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI9aKPvajZAhVJy1MKHdogAcMQ6AEISjAF#v=onepage&q=springer%20data%20electrical%20properties%20materials&f=false

Comment: @CoryG - A traditional comprehensive physical data source is the so called Landolt-Börnstein with many tomes. Here you'll find an online version: https://www.springernature.com/gp/librarians/products/product-types/database/springermaterials?countryChanged=true . You will be surprised what you will find just making a search for Osmium and Iridium there. I just tried it.

Comment: @freecharly I can't use it because I don't have a subscription.

Comment: @CoryG Maybe you can go to a university library. They should have access.

Comment: @CoryG - Also the National Institute of Standards and Technology https://www.nist.gov might have the data.